# Share JWT Across Multiple Vue.js Apps

Tags: vue.js

Is there a way to share JWT token across multiple Vue.js apps installed on the same domain.  For example, the main app is where a user can login and conduct client transactions. Then a reviews app in the sub directory where users can only post reviews.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use cookies, each app has to request the token from the backend(s). If there is more than one backend, the question becomes how to share the jwt between the backends. One solution to this problem is called [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on).

Otherwise, [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) are excellent for sharing data between sessions on a domain.

Comment: Unfortunately, my backend apis can do only JWT.  I dont' want to rewrite the backend.

Comment: Are the jwt applications calling different backends, or do you only have one backend?

Comment: Most likely different backends but the JWT token generator can have the same key to decode the token